# Rails App Precompiling Assets Failed Error When Pushing to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Before marking this as a duplicate--I have seen other threads with the same issue and the solution was always to include 
    "config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false"
to my config/application.rb profile and I've done that but the error remains. Here's my application.rb file:

```
require_relative 'boot'

require 'rails/all'

Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module SampleApp
   class Application < Rails::Application

   config.load_defaults 5.2

   config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false

  end
end
```

And here's the full error message when I run $ git push heroku master:

```
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected
```

Comment: this is not the full error. You stripped the reason, so please add whole error you see while pushing to Heroku.

Comment: To https://git.heroku.com/pinterestingwg.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/pinterestingwg.git'

Comment: Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: No, he just wants the whole error output put in there.  There is information in the output that will be useful.  Above the snippet what you pasted there will be some indications to what went wrong, so if you can edit the question and paste the whole heroku output you get when trying to deploy.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$rake assets:precompile`
Hope this will solve your problem!